# Can't access android/drawable Icon-Resource

Tags: android, xml, icons, android-optionsmenu

I'm creating a Optionsmenu, for that I use the Android Icon-Resource. But I can't access them, what am I doing wrong. What do I need to change?

Here's the Code of my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/Videos"
          android:icon="@android/drawable/ic_menu_view"
          android:title="Videos" />

    <item android:id="@+id/Bio"
          android:icon="@android/drawable/ic_menu_friendlist"
          android:title="Biographie" />

    <item android:id="@+id/Support"
          android:icon="@android/drawable/ic_menu_star"
          android:title="Support" />

</menu>
```

thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are almost correct, when accessing framework resources you have to prefix the resource type with `android:` since you are [using the android package](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml) here. Which means it should not be

```
android:icon="@android/drawable/ic_menu_view"
```

but

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
```

instead for example *(note the colon between android and drawable instead of a forward slash)*.

---

Also note that you can't access some resources, since they are not public, such as the `ic_menu_star` you are using here. You have to copy them to your projects drawable folders, which means you have to access them via a normal `@drawable/ic_menu_star` after doing that. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589753/android-drawable-ic-menu-star-not-working) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
```

instead of :

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_view"
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/Videos"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_view"
      android:title="Videos" />

<item android:id="@+id/Bio"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_friendlist"
      android:title="Biographie" />

<item android:id="@+id/Support"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_star"
      android:title="Support" />
```

I think @android/drawable/ is incorrect. You should use instead @drawable/

You can see it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Hope this helps...