# Android application does not compile with ic_menu_refresh

Tags: android

I have some small menu in my application, and I want to use Android's icons.
For example, with code, working OK:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mnuMainHelp"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/android:ic_menu_help"
    android:title="@string/menu_main_help">
</item>
```

But if I put next code, app will not compile:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mnuMainUpdateDB"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/android:ic_menu_refresh"
    android:title="@string/menu_main_update_db">
</item>
```

The error message is:

**... \res\menu\main_menu.xml:4: error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/android:ic_menu_refresh').**

Where I was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have that resource as public that is why you get that errorError: Resource is not public

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Here's the menu drawables.

```
int ic_menu_add 
int ic_menu_agenda  
int ic_menu_always_landscape_portrait   
int ic_menu_call    
int ic_menu_camera  
int ic_menu_close_clear_cancel  
int ic_menu_compass 
int ic_menu_crop    
int ic_menu_day 
int ic_menu_delete  
int ic_menu_directions  
int ic_menu_edit    
int ic_menu_gallery 
int ic_menu_help  // you have this  
int ic_menu_info_details    
int ic_menu_manage  
int ic_menu_mapmode 
int ic_menu_month   
int ic_menu_more    
int ic_menu_my_calendar 
int ic_menu_mylocation  
int ic_menu_myplaces    
int ic_menu_preferences 
int ic_menu_recent_history  
int ic_menu_report_image    
int ic_menu_revert  
int ic_menu_rotate  
int ic_menu_save    
int ic_menu_search  
int ic_menu_send    
int ic_menu_set_as  
int ic_menu_share   
int ic_menu_slideshow   
int ic_menu_sort_alphabetically 
int ic_menu_sort_by_size    
int ic_menu_today   
int ic_menu_upload  
int ic_menu_upload_you_tube 
int ic_menu_view    
int ic_menu_week    
int ic_menu_zoom
```

But according to this

http://androiddrawables.com/Menu.html you have `ic_menu_refresh` and it's probably not public.

Use the one in the 1st link posted

Edit:

Also check this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html

Quoting from the above link

**You should not use drawable resources from the android package**, because they may change between platform versions, causing unforeseen conflicts with your design. Typically, styles are the only resources you should use directly from these resources.

Answer (score 3):

Try android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_refresh" -- except, this doesn't work. See edit below.

EDIT: Apparently some drawables are not public, see [Android drawable ic_menu_star not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589753/android-drawable-ic-menu-star-not-working?rq=1)

You can get copies of the actual resources in the Android source or from http://androiddrawables.com/